# Terraform: How to avoid passing a variable when do a querying

Tags: terraform

I initiailized an provider tencentcloud but it requires the region field to be set. And then I did a data query using data block to get the users. But it always gave me this error: "X-TC-Region" is not allowed. It seems that region should not be passed when doing such a query.  Is there any solutions?
My main.tf is like:

```
provider "tencentcloud" {
  alias = "with_region"
  region = "var.available_zone"
}
```

my users.tf is like:

```
data "tencentcloud_cam_users" "permenant_access" {
    provider = tencentcloud.without_region
    name = "permenant_access"
}

output "account_emails" {
    value = data.tencentcloud_cam_users.permenant_access.user_list[0].email
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will not work the way you are trying it right now. Right now, you are passing a string literal (i.e., "var.available_zone") instead of referencing a variable. Depending on the fact if the variable is defined or not, this should fix it:

```
provider "tencentcloud" {
  alias  = "with_region"
  region = var.available_zone
}
```

Make sure you understand how to reference variables that you define [1].

If you really do not want to use variables in terraform, you will have to provide at least environment variables [2]:

```bash
$ export TENCENTCLOUD_SECRET_ID="my-secret-id"
$ export TENCENTCLOUD_SECRET_KEY="my-secret-key"
$ export TENCENTCLOUD_REGION="ap-guangzhou"
$ terraform plan
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/values/variables#using-input-variable-values

[2] https://registry.terraform.io/providers/tencentcloudstack/tencentcloud/latest/docs#environment-variables